# How to build the transaction needed to have a user pay to mint an NFT

Tags: wallet, nft, minting

I have integrated a Cardano wallet into my site and done some basic interactions.
I am hoping to get a sample, example and/or guidance on how to build the transaction I am interested in implementing:

Scenario:

- User visits my site, connects their wallet.
- User pays an amount of ADA or an amount of a native token to mint an NFT.
- User has NFT in their wallet now, and site can verify it is there as a means of confirming paid membership.

So the transaction I need to build:

User pays an amount of ADA or a native token to mint an NFT.
=> ADA gets transferred from the users wallet to the wallet of the site, NFT gets minted and sent to users wallet.

Has anyone here done this?

Answer (score 1):

This all can be done in a single transaction using [lucid](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid). Suggest you to see examples [here](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/tree/main/src/examples). You can use `payToContract` to pay Ada / native token and simultaneously, `mintAssets` to mint them (in your minting script, check script context to see whether the required amount is getting transferred to required address). Can see a similar example I coded for my project [here](https://github.com/adaplays/adaplays.xyz/blob/main/pages/games/rps/new-game.tsx#L89).